# A struct in a struct in cython

Tags: c, struct, cython

In cython , I need to do a system of node with parent and child ( for a kdtree ). I try this:

```
cdef struct Node:
    int id
    Node *left_child
    Node *right_left
```

But I get a error where a struct cannot contain itself. I can do that in python, so I supposed it's possible with cython / C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cython allows forward definitions, so:

```
cdef struct Node

cdef struct Node:
    int id
    Node *left_child
    Node *right_left
```

You may already know this, but Scipy has very nice kdtree implementations in [pure Python](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.KDTree.html) and [Cython](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.cKDTree.html).

Answer (score -1):

I'm not familiar with cython or cdef--so here goes; have you tried doing this instead?

```
cdef struct Node:
    int id
    struct Node *left_child
    struct Node *right_left
```

Comment: No , not working. I got this error : "Syntax error in C variable declaration"